# Elm - Text.style results in "Cannot read property 'arity'" error

Tags: elm

As soon as I try to set the style of a `Text`, I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'arity' of undefined
    Open the developer console for more details.
```

Developer console gives `TypeError: fun is undefined`.

Elm 0.12, and `http://elm-lang.org/try`
Browsers: Chrome, Firefox

```
titleStyle : Text.Style
titleStyle = 
    { typeface = [ "serif" ]
    , height   = Just 18
    , color    = white
    , bold     = True
    , italic   = False
    , line     = Nothing
    }

main = centered (style titleStyle (toText "hello"))
```

If you change `main` to:

```
main = centered (toText "hello")
```

text renders as expected, with no style.

I can't find any example of `Text.style` on the Elm site -- am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Compiling the one-line program `hello = style defaultStyle (toText "Hello")` fails with the same error.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. https://github.com/elm-lang/Elm/issues/549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by the `style` function not being exported in the standard libraries (Elm/libraries/Native/Text.js)

Fixed in `main` as of 2014-04-01. https://github.com/elm-lang/Elm/issues/549